# JSF page only loads data when backing bean is on session scoped

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

This is my `admin_order_search.xhtml` page and it has a `<p:dataTable>`
and I'm trying to call a `admin_view_order.xhtml` page with the particulate
`order` object

```
<p:column>
   <f:facet name="header">
     <h:outputText value="View" />
   </f:facet>

   <p:commandButton action="admin_view_order?faces-redirect=true" id="view" value="View Info" update="dataTable" actionListener="#{viewOrderController.loadOrder(order)}" />

</p:column>
```

and this is my "admin_view_order.xhtml"

```
<h:form id="orderViewForm">
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" sticky="false" />           

    <p:outputLabel value="#{viewOrderController.order.orderId}"></p:outputLabel>
    <p:outputLabel value="#{viewOrderController.order.customerName}"> </p:outputLabel>

</h:form>
```

and hear is my "ViewOrderController.java" page

```
@Component
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewOrderController implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Order order;

    public void loadOrder(Order order){
        System.out.println("ID : "+order.getOrderId());
        System.out.println("Name : "+order.getCustomerName());
        this.order = order;
    }

    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
}
```

the problem is `admin_view_order.xhtml` shows the order details, only if my `ViewOrderController` is on `@SessionScoped` but I want it to be on `ViewScoped`

Please let me knows how to do that?

Comment: do u knows any better way to do this?

Comment: i can get the Order object within the ViewScoped but i cannot show any properties of that object in my page. there has to be a solution to this kind of a problem

Comment: Are you using spring mvc? Why do you have `@Component` and `@ManagedBean`?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want the Controller to be ViewScoped?

After leaving the view (navigate to admin_view_order.xhtml) a new instance of your controller is used. So the changes you made before (setting the order in loadOrder) are gone.

Comment: that means i have to find a another way to do this, is it?

Comment: Either use SessionScope, or stay on the same view.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do that , is to passing parameter through the GET request ( for example you can pass the id of the order object in **admin_order_search.xhtml** to  , and then recover this id and use it in your backing bean by searching the object with this id ).

This is possible by using view parameters

1-pass the id of the object (add the folowing tag inside your button )

```
<f:param name="id" value="#{viewOrderController.order.orderId}" />
```

2-After that, in your admin_view_order.xhtml page, catch the view param and load the info for that order:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{viewOrderController.newOrderId}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{viewOrderController.loadOrder}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

note that i added an attribut ( newOrderId ) to put the order.orderId into it